# how do i turn on workspaces by command

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher

I installed Compiz, and messed with a few little things, unfortunately i lost the Workspaces Switcher
I tried `gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize 2`
but couldn't get it back, tried to go to Appearance and clicked on it in the behavior but no change
I also looked for a command in terminal, and didn't find any, i am using Ubuntu 13.10
is there any way to get it back without formatting my pc?

Comment: What environment are you using? Gnome?

Comment: no, i use unity

Answer (score 0):

You may reset all Compiz settings to defaults

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```